# How to prove ~ (~P & ~Q) : P ∨ Q by natural deduction

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

Here's another of Tomassi's exercises I can't solve (*Logic*, page 106):

~ (~P & ~Q) : P ∨ Q

I have to use natural deduction and the only rules I know are:

- assumptions,
- modus ponendo ponens,
- modus tollendo tollens,
- double negation,
- reductio ad absurdum,
- conditional proof,
- v-introduction,
- v-elimination,
- and introduction,
- and elimination.

Tomassi's proof consists of 14 steps.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You cannot.....

Comment: Either I can't decipher what you mean by : or this is not provable. (I assumed ~P & ~Q is your premise and P v Q is your desired conclusion).

Comment: @virmaior I'm sorry, I missed a negation symbol in the premise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is first a proof using Klement's proof checker to make sure I have a correct proof.

[image]

Using Tomassi's formatting, this proof might look like the following:

```
¬(¬P & ¬Q) ⊢ P v Q
{1}      1.  ¬(¬P ∧ ¬Q)              Premise
{2}      2.  ¬(P v Q)                Assumption for RAA
{3}      3.  P                       Assumption for RAA
{3}      4.  P v Q                   3 vI (right-hand)
{2,3}    5.  ¬(P v Q) & (P v Q)      2,4 &I
{2}      6.  ¬P                      3,5 RAA
{7}      7.  Q                       Assumption for RAA
{7}      8.  P v Q                   7 vI (left-hand)
{2,7}    9.  ¬(P v Q) & (P v Q)      2,8 &I
{2}     10.  ¬Q                      7,9 RAA
{2}     11.  ¬P & ¬Q                 6,10 &I
{2}     12.  ¬(¬P & ¬Q) & (¬P & ¬Q)  1,11 &I
{1}     13.  ¬¬(P v Q)               2,12 RAA
{1}     14.  P v Q                   13 DNE
```

The strategy is to assume the negative of what one wants to prove, derive a contradiction and then by reduction ad absurdum (RAA) reach the desired answer. That is also done with two subproofs, one on lines 3 through 5 and the other on lines 7 through 9.

The proof uses the following rules and the page numbers where Tomassi defines them:

- Premise-Introduction, page 48
- rule of assumption, page 59
- &-introduction (and-introduction), page 49
- right handed vIntroduction, page 84
- left handed vIntroduction, page 84
- negation introduction (RAA), page 102-3
- double negation-elimination (DNE), page 79

These rules are all defined earlier than page 106 where the exercise appeared. I may have got the dependencies wrong (column 1) or other parts since these were manually inserted.

---

Reference

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Tomassi, P Logic (1999)

Answer (score 2):

The argument schema is not *valid*; check it with both **P** and **Q** false.

Thus, we cannot prove that **(¬P & ¬Q) : P v Q**.

What we can prove is : **¬(¬P & ¬Q) : P v Q**.

*Hint*

1) **¬P** --- assumed [a]

2) **¬Q** --- assumed [b]

3) **¬(P v Q)** --- assumed [c]

4) from 1) and 2) and the premise we get a contradiction, deriving **P** by *Double Negation* and discharging [a]

5) **P v Q** --- from 4)

6) a new contradiction from 3) and 5), deriving **Q** by *Double Negation* and discharging [b]

7) **P v Q** --- from 6)

8) a new contradiction from 3) and 7), deriving **P v Q** by *Double Negation* and discharging [c].